# Firebase - collection group "orderBy" won't display anything

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a problem with using `orderBy` with collectionGroup. I have a collectionGroup named `specificPost` which is used to display different posts. In useEffect I am getting that data and I want to order the data by `createdAt` field. What is the problem? Without `orderBy` this code works just like I want to

Here is the code:

```
const ref2 = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collectionGroup("specificPost")
    .orderBy("createdAt");

  useEffect(() => {
    const readingPost = async () => {
      const data = await ref2.get();
      setPosts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      handleClose();
    };

There are more code in useEffect but it just has more functions for getting other data
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, displaying nothing when I added `orderBy` to `collectionGroup`. It was because I didn't create an index for the collection group.

- Open the console and you will see there's an error about setting index for the collection group. Click the link and create the exemption which is auto generated for your collection group.
- If you can't find the link, you can manually create the exemption in `Firebase console > Firestore Database > Indexes > Single field > Add exemption`.